# Add drawable in resources string.xml

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to add a drawable (ic_myimage) in a string (my_string_name) that I have in the resources string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="my_string_name">Here is my image: @drawable/ic_myimage It looks great</string>
</resources>
```

Is this possible to do? I want the image with the rest of the string to be displayed in my TextView. (Code Below)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_string_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Note: I tried the following which I found on another post but didn't work

```
<string name="my_string_name">Here is my image: [img src=ic_myimage/] It looks great</string>
```

I am using Android Studio and Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by providing text using Spannable string just like that

```
//your drawable    
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.arrow);

//your spannable text "Lorem.... amet"
SpannableString spannableText= new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

//apply image to spannable text 
//0 is the flag
//start and end are the index length where you wantg to put the image
spannableText.setSpan(is, startIndex, End index, 0);

//then, you can  apply this tspannable text to textview
yourTextView.setText(spannableText);
```

Comment: This is the closest answer that solves my problem. Thanks!
I also changed it for those who want the Kotlin version.
`val imageSpan = ImageSpan(applicationContext,R.drawable.ic_myimage )
        val spannableText = SpannableString("Here is my image: ic_myimage It looks great")
        val keyword = "ic_myimage"
        val index = spannableText.indexOf(keyword);
        spannableText.setSpan(imageSpan, index, index + keyword.length, 0)
        myTextView.text = spannableText`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but it is not possible for a Image to be shown inside a Textview the proper way in calling an image from drawable is by the used of ImageView.

Like this one.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_myimage">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to add a couple of images in the same textview, plus some strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please use drawableStart() method of text view of showing icon on left of text view.but you can't  use  icon as a String Text.